# angular.js:13920 Error: show-errors element has no child input elements with a 'name' attribute class

Tags: angularjs, validation, repeat

I have a problem with following code.
It make "angular.js:13920 Error: show-errors element has no child input elements with a 'name' attribute class" error.

```
vm.forminput = [
      { 'title':'Name',
        'variable': 'name',
        'validate':'required'
      },
      { 'title':'Nation',
        'variable': 'nation',
        'validate':'required'
      }]


<div show-errors ng-repeat="item in vm.forminput">
      <input   ng-if="item.variable != 'overview'"   name={{item.variable}} 
          type="text" ng-model="vm.useraccount[item.variable]" id=
         {{item.variable}} class="form-control" placeholder="{{item.title}}"
           ng-required="item.validate">

      <textarea ng-if="item.variable == 'overview'"  
        ng-model="vm.useraccount[item.variable]" name={{item.variable}} id= 
       {{item.variable}} class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" 
         placeholder="{{item.title}}" ng-required="item.validate">
      </textarea>

      <div ng-messages="vm.form.useraccountForm[item.variable].$error"  
          role="alert">
        <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Useraccount 
           {{item.title}} is required.</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

notes:

- when I remove "show-errors" errors disappear but I can't see validate message
- when I remove `ng-if="item.variable != 'overview'"` errors disappear but I have to use this function.

Comment: show-errors is not a standard AngularJS diretive. We have no idea what it's supposed to do, what its code is, etc.

Comment: when it comes to show-errors, I didn't make it, I build my project with "yo meanjs" . And they included this directive.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ng-if` you can use `ng-show`. For textarea it would be:

```
ng-show="item.variable === 'overview'"
```

This will fix the problem, but, because ng-show does not remove elements from DOM, you'll probably need to deal with duplicate element names and id-s. So, instead of just having `name={{item.variable}}`, you'll need to do something like this:

```
name="{{item.variable !== 'overview' ? 'hidden' +  item.variable: item.variable}}"
```

The result will look like this:

```
<div show-errors ng-repeat="item in vm.forminput">
  <input   ng-show="item.variable !== 'overview'"   name="{{item.variable === 'overview' ? 'hidden' +  item.variable : item.variable}}"   
           type="text" ng-model="vm.useraccount[item.variable]" id="{{item.variable === 'overview' ? 'hidden' +  item.variable: item.variable}}"
           class="form-control" placeholder="{{item.title}}"
           ng-required="item.validate">

  <textarea ng-show="item.variable === 'overview'"
            ng-model="vm.useraccount[item.variable]" name="{{item.variable !== 'overview' ? 'hidden' +  item.variable : item.variable}}"  
            id="{{item.variable !== 'overview' ? 'hidden' +  item.variable : item.variable}}"
            class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10"
            placeholder="{{item.title}}" ng-required="item.validate">
  </textarea>

  <div ng-messages="vm.form.useraccountForm[item.variable].$error"
       role="alert">
    <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Useraccount
      {{item.title}} is required.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```